# Best Approach for Send Value for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, model-view-controller

I don't have any problem about sending values between `View Controllers`, but **I don't like my approach for this**, I use `prepareForSegue` method to send values between `View Controllers` but today I realized something and I didn't like it.

Lets think about this, If I have 3 `View Controllers` and I fetched some values from somewhere on Internet like Parse.com in `First View Controller` which is in `Array` of `someObjects`, I have to reuse this array of someObjects in `Third View Controller` because **I don't want to refetch objects on Network.** I used `prepareForSegue` method for passing value to `Second View Controller` and after that I used again this approach to pass value `Third View Contoller` and I realized **What if I have 10 View Controller or more ?**

**What is the best approach in this case ?** How can I store the values in Global Property ?

Thank you !

Comment: What you are doing is the best approach.

Comment: You can declare `someObjects` varibale as global property by declaring at the top scope, for example: `var someObjects: [String]! class AppDelegate {}` or use static variable

Comment: @maddy thank you, but what if I have 10 View Controller, Should I always send value with prepareForSegue method ?